# is there any doctrine 2 fields name restriction

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="album")
 */
 class Album
 {
   ...
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="album")
    */
   private $images;
   ...
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 */
class Image
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="album_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $album; 
    ...
```

so when I try in AlbumRepository do the next

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->leftJoin('a.images', 'i');
var_dump($qb->getQuery()->getSQL());
```

it lead me to the error:

```
Class Entity\\Album has no association named images at ...
```

But if I change `images` to any other name, for example `aaa` or `aimages` in this 3 places (and run console doctrine:generate:entities for the bundle) everything works well.

So my question is there any restrictions for fields name for related entities?

Symfony 2.8, doctrine 2.4.8

Comment: Do you have `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourBundleHere\Repository\AlbumRepository")` annotaion at the Album entity?

Comment: Yes, sure. It's autogenerated after running console doctrine:generate:entities